# Spotfire custom format column / tooltip via IronPython or TERR

Tags: ironpython, spotfire, terr

I have a visualization that plots from a data table that is being replaced by a TERR function every time a marking is changed.  The problem is that my custom formatting for the table columns is lost every time the table is replaced.   Basically I want a few of my tooltips based on my columns to have a custom number format that I've defined. Every time I remark, the table is replaced, and the formatting is lost.   I've thought about a few different solutions:

- Format the table in TERR using some kind of attr($map) function, and the formatting should be inherited by the tooltip.  Problem is - I can't find any examples on how to do this...
- Format the table columns in Python -  but the formatting is not being inherited by the tooltip
- Format the tooltip directly in Python - no idea how to do this.

Anyone have any ideas?

Here's the column formatting code:

```
formatter=DataType.Real.CreateLocalizedFormatter()
formatter.Category=NumberFormatCategory.Number

formatter.DecimalDigits=0
formatter.GroupSeparatorEnabled = 1 # not sure what this does
# I actually want to apply a Custom Short number format that I've defined

for cc in table.Columns:
    if cc.Name == "myCol":    
        cc.Properties.Formatter=formatter
```

Comment: thanks for providing the column formatter code!

Comment: I'm also looking to edit/customize tooltips.